# How to reset Jsession Id after successful user login

Tags: session, webserver, websphere, session-variables, session-cookies

I am working on the GWT-P web application where the JSession Id will not change even after user login which is raised by security team. so i had implemented the below code for to change the Jsession id after successful login and its working fine in my local dev mode, But in the deployment that is not working. i dont know how its working fine in dev mode and why its not working in production.

In dev am using **Jetty Server** and back-end code for reset the JSession ID

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session!=null && !session.isNew()) {
    session.invalidate();
}
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); // create the session
```

But in deployment mode am using application server as **WebSphere**

and also the Jsession id value looks different on dev mode compare to deployment mode.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You're using two totally different engines for development and deployment. So don't wonder that you've a different behavior.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254556

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21210881

Comment: Yeah ur correct obviously it will be different...and how can i reset the JSession id in webSphere after user login the application..